# Linking two Dimension Tables

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensions, star-schema, fact-table

I am new to Data warehousing and have set up multiple Dimension Tables and Fact Tables using a STAR schema. I have a question that using STAR schema, can two dimensions be linked together using a primary key/foreign key approach.  I have read that two dimensions can only be linked in a FACT table ? Is this correct ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions can reference another dimension. Just being wary of linking them means there is a chance of explosive growth due to Type2 SCD changes. This approach is called an outrigger dimension used when a dimension table is snowflaked. Outriggers are tables or entities that are shared by more than one dimension.

Comment: a query to get all locations linked to a product would be meaningful, and querying a smaller dimension table compared to a large fact table would be meaningful as well

Comment: Dimensions can reference another dimension as you said.  But linking them means there is a chance of explosive growth due to Type2 SCD changes. This is what we call an outrigger dimension which is used when a dimension table is snowflaked. Outriggers are tables or entities that are shared by more than one dimension. I've edited the answer with this comment.